# Conflict when using the same slug name for page and post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have some problems with permalink in wordpress.

I have created a page "grid-services" that have the permalink : 
example.com/grid-services/

I also registered and costum post type "markets", and after i created a market named "grid-services", with the permalink: 
example.com/markets/grid-services/

THE PROBLEM
when i try to access the example.com/grid-services/  url, it automaticly redirect me to example.com/markets/grid-services/ page url

WHAT I HAVE TRIED
When i register the post type i have tried to change the code in diferent combination, but nothing seems to work.

```
register_post_type( 'markets',
array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'supports' => $supports,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'rewrite' => array("slug" => "markets"),
  'has_archive' => false,
)
```

);

What can be the problem?

Comment: Add a filter to ''wp_insert_post_data'. There you can add some extra value with the slug. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first project in wordpress, can you be more specific please?

Comment: Go through following article -
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly i have find a simple answer, i just removed the permalink from costum post
adding this 2 settings

```
 'public' => false,
  'show_ui' => true,
```

Now all it seems to be ok.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you another function, which can help you --

```
function wp_cpt_unique_post_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
    if ( in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) )
        return $slug;

    global $wpdb, $wp_rewrite;

    // store slug made by original function
    $wp_slug = $slug;

    // reset slug to original slug
    $slug = $original_slug;

    $feeds = $wp_rewrite->feeds;
    if ( ! is_array( $feeds ) )
        $feeds = array();

    $hierarchical_post_types = get_post_types( array('hierarchical' => true) );
    if ( 'attachment' == $post_type ) {
        // Attachment slugs must be unique across all types.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_ID ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_attachment_slug', false, $slug ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr ($slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_ID ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) ) {
        if ( 'nav_menu_item' == $post_type )
            return $slug;
        // Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
        // namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', false, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    } else {
        // Post slugs must be unique across all posts.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', false, $slug, $post_type ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    }

    return $slug;
}
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'wp_cpt_unique_post_slug', 10, 6);
```